# How to create a different pojo from xml entity string value in java

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

My use-case is quite limited and I have many constraints in place.

Firstly I only have a XML of a sample structure as defined below. I do not have a schema definition. My requirement and implementation is quite restricted in approach.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<items>
    <item>
        <content_id>56789012</content_id>
        <unique_record_id>B-123456</unique_record_id>
        <title>ABC</title>
        <type>board</type>
        <dfield>098765</dfield>
        <abn>11 222 333 444</abn>
        <cfield>Yes</cfield>
        <bfield>Goodness me</bfield>
        <afield>ABCD</afield>
    </item>
    <item>
        <content_id>1234</content_id>
        <unique_record_id>D-789</unique_record_id>
        <title>Member</title>
        <type>role</type>
        <contact>90000</contact>
        <role_belongs_to>56789012</role_belongs_to>
        <updated>23/07/2018 - 3:30pm</updated>
        <importance>90</importance>
    </item>
    <item>
        <content_id>90000</content_id>
        <unique_record_id>D-654321</unique_record_id>
        <title>Someone Else</title>
        <type>person</type>
        <salutation>Ms.</salutation>
        <first_name>Someone</first_name>
        <last_name>Else</last_name>
    </item>
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
</items>
```

The model above is a simple representation of the xml I will be given (no im not dealing with persons, companies data models :) ). Note that there are many item types. The field ***type***, is effectively the POJO I want to create. There are also relationships between items. Note that the relationships are generally 1 to many.

i.e.

- a person can have many roles
- a person can work for many boards
- a person can work for many organisations

There are 1 to 1 relationships as well, i.e.:

- a role can belong to only 1 organisation
- a few others as well.....

---

My Target:

- I would like to know the cleanest way to extract all relationships
- create associated pojo list of all items with the correct
  pojo type
- denormalise the xml into a new xml structure sample defined below.

---

I know I could write quite a bit of code to strip the xml and use reflection to create the POJO once the xml is unmarshaled and iterate.

I am looking for the cleanest way, I am open to JAXB, SAX or any other library which can simplify the task at hand.

Denormalised output example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<items>
    <Person>
        <content_id>90000</content_id>
        <unique_record_id>D-654321</unique_record_id>
        <title>Someone Else</title>
        <salutation>Ms.</salutation>
        <first_name>Someone</first_name>
        <last_name>Else</last_name>
        <role>
            <content_id>1234</content_id>
            <unique_record_id>D-789</unique_record_id>
            <title>Member</title>
            <role_belongs_to>
                <board>
                    <content_id>56789012</content_id>
                    <unique_record_id>B-123456</unique_record_id>
                    <title>ABC</title>
                    <dfield>098765</dfield>
                    <abn>11 222 333 444</abn>
                    <cfield>Yes</cfield>
                    <bfield>Goodness me</bfield>
                    <afield>ABCD</afield>
                </board>
            </role_belongs_to>
            <updated>23/07/2018 - 3:30pm</updated>
            <importance>90</importance>
        </role>

    </Person>
    .
    .
</items>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting combination of requirements. I got it to work with SimpleXml. It's up to you if you find this clean enough. First some POJOs:

```
public class Items {
    @XmlName("item")
    @XmlAbstractClass(tag="type", types={
        @TypeMap(name="board", type=Board.class),
        @TypeMap(name="role", type=Role.class),
        @TypeMap(name="person", type=Person.class)
    })
    public List<Item> items;
}

abstract class Item {
    @XmlName("content_id")
    public Integer contentId;
}
public class Board extends Item {
    String abn;
}
public class Role extends Item {
    @XmlNoExport
    @XmlName("role_belongs_to")
    Integer boardId;
    @XmlNoImport
    @XmlWrapperTag("role_belongs_to")
    Board board;
}
public class Person extends Item {
    @XmlNoExport
    @XmlName("has_role")
    public Integer hasRole;
    @XmlNoImport
    public Role role;
}

@XmlName("items")
public class PersonList {
    @XmlName("Person")
    public List<Person> persons;
}
```

Next we serialize the xml to an items list:

```
final SimpleXml simple = new SimpleXml();
final Items items = simple.fromXml(xml, Items.class);
```

Then we need to do some moving around in memory:

```
final Map<Integer, Board> boards = new HashMap<>();
items.items.forEach(item -> { if (item instanceof Board) boards.put(item.contentId, (Board)item); });
final Map<Integer, Role> roles = new HashMap<>();
items.items.forEach(item -> { if (item instanceof Role) roles.put(item.contentId, (Role)item); });
final List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
items.items.forEach(item -> { if (item instanceof Person) persons.add((Person)item); });

roles.values().forEach(role -> role.board = boards.get(role.boardId));
persons.forEach(person -> person.role = roles.get(person.hasRole));
```

And finally serialize the results and print:

```
final PersonList pl = new PersonList();
pl.persons = persons;
System.out.println(simple.toXml(pl));
```

Should print out exactly what you want. I didn't quite see how you assigned roles to Persons so I made up a `has_role` field and used that. Of course you can do whatever.

SimpleXml is in maven central:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.codemonstur</groupId>
    <artifactId>simplexml</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This is a good answer, I ended up doing something similar except i ended up simply using a stax parser. I think I will change the code to a similar change of the above. Its more robust.